# Run callback to change to current directory when opening files

Tags: matlab

When I open MATLAB, it defaults to open to `/home/myUser`. Whenever I open a file interactively (say I run Simulink and click "Open...") the dialog will start in `/home/myUser`. Then I might go into `/home/myUser/myDir1/myDir2/` before clicking on `myModel.mdl`.

If I open a different Simulink file with the "Open..." dialog again, it'll kick me back to `/home/myUser`. Note that this is regardless of file, I'm just using Simulink as an example. I would like to keep it in `/home/myUser/myDir1/myDir2`, meaning I should be in the same directory as the last file I just opened (or saved).

Programatically, I would set up a callback to `cd` into whatever directory the file I chose was in after selecting the file using `uigetfile`. Is this possible to do just with MATLAB's own "Open" or "Save As" commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wrapper for `uigetfile` that remembers the last director [on the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9254-uigetfile2). You can get [wrappers for the other file dialogs](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=authorid%3A21403) as well from the same author.

**EDIT**

How to overload the built-in `uigetdir` etc.

(1) Rename `uigetdir2` to `uigetdir`, and make sure it's in a path that has precedence over the path for the built-in function (this should be the case by default).

<strike>(2) Use [BUILTIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/builtin.html) to ensure that the new function doesn't call itself.</strike>

(2) Since `uigetdir` is implemented as a .m-file, as opposed to being compiled (like `sum`), the `builtin` command doesn't work for it. Thus, open `uigetdir`, find the private function `uigetdir_helper` (which is private, so we can't call it), and finally uncover the java method (that turns out to have changed from R2011a to R2011b. Yay.). This allows us to finally overload `uigetdir` at the cost of having to parse the input ourselves.

Here's lines 37 to 67 from the modified `uigetdir`

```
%% Check passed arguments and load saved directory
% if start path is specified and not empty call uigetdir with arguments
% from user, if no arguments are passed or start path is empty load saved
% directory from mat file

% parse inputs
parserObj = inputParser;
parserObj.FunctionName = 'uigetdir';
parserObj.addOptional('startPath',[],@(x)exist(x,'dir'));
parserObj.addOptional('dialogTitle','Please choose directory',@ischar);

parserObj.parse(varargin{:});
inputList = parserObj.Results;


% create directory dialog instance - this has changed from 2011a to 2011b
if verLessThan('matlab','7.13')
    dirdlg = UiDialog.UiDirDialog();
else
    dirdlg = matlab.ui.internal.dialog.FolderChooser();
end
dirdlg.InitialPathName = inputList.startPath;
dirdlg.Title = inputList.dialogTitle;


if nargin > 0 && ~isempty(inputList.startPath)
    % call dirdlg instead of uigetdir to avoid infinite recursion
     dirdlg.show();

    % if dirname empty, return 0 for uigetdir.
    directory_name = dirdlg.SelectedFolder;
else
    % set default dialog open directory to the present working directory
    lastDir = pwd;
    % load last data directory
    if exist(lastDirMat, 'file') ~= 0
        % lastDirMat mat file exists, load it
        load('-mat', lastDirMat)
        % check if lastDataDir variable exists and contains a valid path
        if (exist('lastUsedDir', 'var') == 1) && ...
                (exist(lastUsedDir, 'dir') == 7)
            % set default dialog open directory
            lastDir = lastUsedDir;
        end
    end

    dirdlg.InitialPathName = lastDir;

    % call dirdlg instead of uigetdir to avoid infinite recursion
     dirdlg.show();

    % if dirname empty, return 0 for uigetdir.
    directory_name = dirdlg.SelectedFolder;

end
```

Comment: this is good for my own programs that depend on this functionality, but i would like MATLAB to do this by default. can I overload their implementation for when I click on "Open" or "Save As" in the main command window?

Comment: @strictlyrude27: Sure. Just rename `uigetdir2` with `uigetdir`. If the path to your user-defined files is before the Matlab paths (check the output of `path`, you're overloading the Matlab versions.

Comment: I downloaded `uigetdir2` etc and tried opening a file from Simulink; I get a maximum recursion error from `pwd`. :(

Comment: `uigetfile2` is a wrapper around uigetfile (meaning it calls the builtin function internally). So if you rename `uigetfile2` into `uigetfile` it will keep calling itself causing the maximum recursion error eventually (same goes for the other functions).

Comment: @strictlyrude27,@Amro: Right. You have to use `builtin` to fix this. See my edit.

Comment: Quite odd - I get an error: "Error using **builtin**: Cannot find function 'uigetfile'". Of course, typing `uigetfile` at the command window (not overloading) opens the correct dialog.

Comment: @strictlyrude27: Aw man. I found the problem, will update soon. Sorry.

Comment: @strictlyrude27,@Amro: It turns out that you can't use `builtin` for a TMW .m-file. Worse, it's not the first time this has happened to me. Thus, overloading is a little more difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to guess it's about as difficult for `uigetfile` and `uiputfile` as well..

Comment: @strictlyrude27: Fortunately, it's no that hard. The input parsing you might be able lift from of the m-file, and the java call is easy to be found if you dig a bit.

Comment: @Jonas - I feel a little over my head here. All I need to do is parse the inputs, then call the underlying Java code in `uiputfile` and `uigetfile`? Any assistance here would be appreciated.. I do know that the helper file is `uigetputfile_helper.m`.

Comment: @strictlyrude27: You're absolutely right. Alternatively, you could also modify the code of uigetputfile_helper so that it remembers the last directory. Only issue with this is that you'll have to make the same modification whenever you install a new version.